# Le/la/un/une or nothing after these prepositional locutions?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, articles, locutions

Can you please explain me if we combine these expressions with the articles?

- *En cas de*
- *À défaut de*
- *Sans*
- *Faute de*
- *Par manque de*
- *À condition de*
- *À force de*
- *À cause de*
- *Grace à*
- *En raison de*
- *Par suite de*
- *Tant de*
- *Sous peine de*
- *Sauf*

Does it depend on the context or on the used expression?

And also:

- À l'opposé de
- À l'inverse de
- Malgré
- Au risque de
- Quitte à
- À l'instar de
- À l'image de
- Différent de
- En comparaison de
- Conformément à
- Selon
- À la mesure de

Answer (score 1):

I'll mark with an ø when it's nothing and give examples:

> En cas de ø doute
>
> À défaut de ø réponse sous quinzaine
>
> Sans [un|le] formulaire adéquat
>
> Faute de ø preuves
>
> Par manque de ø temps
>
> À cause [de la pluie | d'un incident]
>
> Grâce à [l' | une] aide (exception : Grâce à Dieu)
>
> En raison [de la pluie | d'un incident]
>
> Tant de ø joie
>
> Sous peine de ø contravention

These need to be followed by verbs in the infinitive form:

> À condition de faire
>
> À force de faire

Comment: On peut également dire : « À défaut d'une réponse ... » ; « Sans objet » ; « À cause de lui » ; « Grâce à lui » ...